# Disabled option gets submitted

Tags: html, html-select, disabled-input

I found that an old code has been submitting illegal values into DB from time to time.
I have a select with many options and between options there are some "Headings" that I have disabled.

MYSQL field for errorcode is varchar(2). I have found some "SU" values from that field. That means that the first option, that is disabled, gets submitted.

I looked at the page with IE, Firefox and Chrome and in all of the browsers the first option was disabled and i couldn't select it. I don't have an idea how to debug it.

How to solve this?

```
<td bgcolor="#E1E1E1">
    <select name=errorcode[] style="width:350">
        <option disabled="disabled">SU***** ***:</option>
        <option value="0">&nbsp;[0] SU***** ***</option>
        <option value="1">&nbsp;[1] SU***** ***</option>
        <option value="2">&nbsp;[2] SU***** ***</option>
        <option value="3">&nbsp;[3] SU***** ***</option>
        <option value="4">&nbsp;[4] SU***** ***</option>
        <option value="5">&nbsp;[5] SU***** ***</option>
        <option value="6">&nbsp;[6] SU***** ***</option>
        <option value="7">&nbsp;[7] SU***** ***</option>
        <option value="8">&nbsp;[8] SU***** ***</option>
        <option value="10">&nbsp;[10] SU***** ***</option>
        <option value="12">&nbsp;[12] SU***** ***</option>
        <option value="13">&nbsp;[13] SU***** ***</option>
        <option value="14">&nbsp;[14] SU***** ***</option>
        <option value="15">&nbsp;[15] SU***** ***</option>
        <option disabled="disabled">PR******* ***:</option>
        <option value="40">&nbsp;[40] PI******** ***</option>
        <option value="41">&nbsp;[41] PI******** ***</option>
        <option value="42">&nbsp;[42] PI******** ***</option>
        <option value="43">&nbsp;[43] PI******** ***</option>
        <option value="44">&nbsp;[44] PI******** ***</option>
        <option value="46">&nbsp;[46] PI******** ***</option>
        <option value="47">&nbsp;[47] PI******** ***</option>
        <option disabled="disabled">KO**** ***:</option>
        <option value="50">&nbsp;[50] KO**** ***</option>
        <option value="51">&nbsp;[51] KO**** ***</option>
        <option value="52">&nbsp;[52] KO**** ***</option>
        <option value="53">&nbsp;[53] KO**** ***</option>
        <option value="54">&nbsp;[54] KO**** ***</option>
        <option value="55">&nbsp;[55] KO**** ***</option>
        <option value="56">&nbsp;[56] KO**** ***</option>
        <option value="57">&nbsp;[57] KO**** ***</option>
        <option value="58">&nbsp;[58] KO**** ***</option>
        <option value="58">&nbsp;[59] KO**** ***</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Are you ajaxing to the server?

Comment: No. But it is inside for ($i=0, $i<=10, $i++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert your code to something like:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

More info: [w3schools optgroup](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp)

It's better way to set headings.

Comment: I'd link[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) instead